# How can i add a beamer LateX file to the main LateX file?

Tags: beamer, subfiles

I am trying to add a Beamer LateX file to my main LateX file using the command subfile. After some research, I found the \usepackage{beamerarticle} package that actually helped me insert it into the main text. The problem here is that half of the page is cut and the form looks pretty different. Here is an example:

**Beamer LateX example**

[image]

**Final Result**

[image]

Only the bottom 2 images stayed in the main text.

Any help would be valuable. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't try to include beamer source just include the frames via `\includegraphics[page=..]{beamerfile.pdf}`

Comment: Are you maybe using columns for your beamer slide? If yes beamerarticle normally disables them, but you can some basic functionality back with https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/766 . Please add a minimal reproducible example to your question so we can what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle looks like a very good solution. Quick question: Is it possible to add more pages with this command or should I put each page individually?

Comment: with includegraphics one page at a time but also look at pdfpages package

Comment: ok, thank you very much!!